# how to get which option was pre selected in mongodb in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

when i get preselected value from mongodb and show it in option this data has not show me

from router

```
router.get('/edit_products/:id', /*isAdmin,*/ function (req, res) {
  var errors;
  if (req.session.errors)
    errors = req.session.errors;
  req.session.errors = null;
  Category.find(function (err, categories) {
    Product.findById(req.params.id, function (err, p) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/products');
      } else {
        var galleryDir = 'public/product_images/' + p._id + '/gallery';
        var galleryImages = null;

        fs.readdir(galleryDir, function (err, files) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            galleryImages = files;

            res.render('edit_products', {
              productName: p.productName,
              errors: errors,
              information: p.information,
              categories: categories,
              category: p.category.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(),
              price: parseFloat(p.price).toFixed(2),
              imagePath: p.imagePath,
              galleryImages: galleryImages,
              id: p._id
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });

  });

});
```

and this from template

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Category</label>
        
        <select name="category" class="form-control">
            {{#each categories as |cat|}}
            <option value="{{cat.slug}}"
            {{#CheckIfSlugEqualCat "category"}}
                    selected="selected"        
            {{/CheckIfSlugEqualCat}}
            >{{this.title}}</option>
            {{/each}}    
        </select>
    </div>
```

and this helper function for condition from app.js

```
CheckIfSlugEqualCat: function (category, options) {
  if (this.slug === category) {
      return options.fn(this);
  } else {
      return options.inverse(this);
  }
},
```

what can i do to get preselected data and show it in option when get edit page